# Calling Linq.Min on same IEnumerable returns different result

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable, min

I have a weird thing going on where `min` and `min2` return different values while I am debugging, any reason why?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGroupingOfTimesAndDistances()
{
    // arrange
    ...
    var routes = network.GetNetworkRoutes(startPoint, endPoints); // this yields one at a time

    // act
    routes.ToBandings();
}

public static bool ToBandings(this IEnumerable<INetworkRoute> enumerable)
{
    var min = enumerable.Min(nr => nr.Value.Distance);
    var min2 = enumerable.Min(nr => nr.Value.Distance);
    return true;
}
```

I am running this code from the MS Test Runner if that is important. Framework 4.5, using VS 2013.

Comment: Can you provide complete code that reproduces this?

Comment: "coming from the DB" doesn't really tell us much. Has it already been fetched into a `List<T>` or something like that? Please give us more context. *In general* you can't assume that an `IEnumerable<T>` will give you the same results every time you iterate over it, although that's true for many implementations.

Comment: What I would look at is, do both calls produce a database query, if so what is the query and what results does it produce.

Comment: @Muhammad: Well in some cases you *can* expect the answer to be the same - but it really depends on the data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen if `enumerable` changes between the calls. It seems `GetNetworkRoutes` uses lazy evalution to return the result. And that's why it's result is enumerated each time you call `Min` method on it. So the second returns different results and that's why the min. value you get is different. If you want to prevent this use `ToList` or `ToArray` method to materialize the results. And pass it to your method.